# Call IntentService from BroadcastReceiver in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to start a service from broadcast receiver in Android wear? I was able to start service from activity.

I tried the same:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ServiceToSendData.class);
context.startService(i);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50000010 } in com.ysz.demo.ScreenDetectionReceiver@b3d20fc0
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:769)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3848)
       at com.ysz.demo.ScreenDetectionReceiver.trigger(ScreenDetectionReceiver.java:68)
       at      com.ysz.demo.ScreenDetectionReceiver.checktimeandsendtoshake(ScreenDetectionReceiver.java:60)  at com.ysz.demo.ScreenDetectionReceiver.onReceive(ScreenDetectionReceiver.java:41)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:759)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the call stack, the only possible explanation for this exception is that `context` is null.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ServiceToSendData.class);

...

public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);  // <- Line 3848
}

...

public ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls) {
    mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();  // <- Line 77
    mClass = cls.getName();
}
```

Is that the case?

Comment: @TheDevMan `pkg.getPackageName()` is throwing an NPE. That means `pkg` is null. `pkg` is passed from the `Intent` constructor, it's the first parameter, `context`. Which means that in your `new Intent(context, ServiceToSendData.class);`, `context` must be null.

Comment: Sorry I am not really sure what you are trying to say because I trying this on Android Wear. I am trying to figure out how to call a service from broadcast receiver in Android wear?

Comment: @TheDevMan What I mean is: have you checked that `context` is not null in `ScreenDetectionReceiver.trigger()`?

Comment: Yeah. context is Null.. How to fix this part?

Comment: @TheDevMan Well, where did you get the `context` from? Is it the parameter to `onReceive()`? Please post the code of `ScreenDetectionReceiver.trigger`.

Comment: My bad. I didn't call the context in OnRecieve part and hence it was always null. Thanks for headup!

Comment: @TheDevMan Yeah, had to be that. Well, I'm glad it's solved :)